# How to fix "java the unnamed module reads package x from both y and z"

Tags: java, javafx, htmlunit

I am new to Java. I am trying to login a website with htmlunit. I got these errors. How can I fix it. Its JDK 11. Here is my code:

```
try {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) 
    webClient.getPage("http://ubs.yalova.edu.tr");
    HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("loginForm");
    form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute("myUsername");
    form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("myPassword");

    page = form.getInputByValue("GİRİŞ YAP").click();

    System.out.println(page.asText());
   } catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

//module-info.java
    module HelloWorld {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires htmlunit;

    opens sample;
}
```

All errors here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Cm7m23RcjS/

Comment: is it java 9???

Comment: its JDK 11 @snr

Comment: Do you need to use modules? Or can you just go without?

Comment: can you try it without modularization and putting all Xerces Jars on Java’s classpath?

Comment: I need to use them. I deleted xml.apis. I got "Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in module" error message. @Michael

Comment: It didnt work for me @snr